# I'm seeking a wildcard character for my function in R, but don't know what to search?

Tags: r, function, arguments

### Reproducible example

I seek to build a function to build regressions based on a subset of data. My reproducible example is below:

```
set.seed(1) # Reproducibility

testdat <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                      y = rnorm(100),
                      factor = sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=T)) # Create a dummy data set

test.model <- function(input.factor = NULL){
  model.out = lm(y~x,data = testdat[which(testdat$factor == input.factor),])
} # Create a function that regresses x against y, after subsetting

modelA <- test.model(input.factor = "A") # Works fine
modelB <- test.model(input.factor = "B") # Also works fine
modelAll <- test.model(input.factor = "???") # I'm seeking the keyword for all the data here
```

### Problem

My function works fine for cases where `input.factor = "A"` or `"B"`, but I want to use the function on the entire data set. I've tried using the `*` wildcard, but that only seems to work for regular expressions.

My question is, **what string do I need to type in  `input.factor =`  to select all values of the  `factor` variable?**

**PS** As a statistician I know that I should include the `factor` variable in the regression itself. However, my actual use case is a more complicated model with much more data, so computing a complete model takes too much time.

Comment: Just use an `if` statement in your function, and if `input.factor` is NULL (the default) run the regression without subsetting.

Comment: Maybe `unique(testdat$factor)` and change your condition in function to `testdat[which(testdat$factor %in% input.factor)`

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this:

```
test.model <- function(input.factor = NULL){
  if (is.null(input.factor)){
    model.out = lm(y~x,data = testdata)
  } else{
    model.out = lm(y~x,data = testdat[which(testdat$factor == input.factor),])
  }
 model.out
} #
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Ronak already pointed out, you have to make 2 changes.

The function call `test.model` and your "wildcard". * is SQL-synthax, but you can ask for all the unique names in the dataset with `unique()`.

```
set.seed(1) # Reproducibility

testdat <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                      y = rnorm(100),
                      factor = sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=T)) # Create a dummy data set

test.model <- function(input.factor = NULL){
  model.out = lm(y~x,data = testdat[which(testdat$factor %in% input.factor),])
} # Create a function that regresses x against y, after subsetting

modelA <- test.model(input.factor = "A") # Works fine
modelB <- test.model(input.factor = "B") # Also works fine
modelAll <- test.model(input.factor = unique(testdat$factor))
```